# Sendmail does not send emails from GCE VM instance

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine, sendmail

I have installed a WordPress website on my Google Cloud Compute Engine, but I am not able to send mail. So after searching the internet discovered [Sendmail](http://lukepeters.me/blog/getting-the-php-mail-function-to-work-on-ubuntu).

Installed and configured the latest version by:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Ran the sendemail config, answered "yes" to everything:

```
$ sudo sendmailconfig
```

Edited the `127.0.0.1 localhost instance-1` line (instance-1 is my Google cloud instance):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts # changed
```

Restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

When I run the command below in my terminal, nothing happens, and I am not be able to run commands anymore. So it looks like the process is not ending.

```
$ sendmail example@email.com
```

The output of `$ date | sendmail -v example@email.com` returns:

```
example@email.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 instance-1.c.myproject.internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-8; Wed, 24 Aug 2016 09:42:18 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO instance-1.c.myproject.internal
250-instance-1.c.myproject.internal Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<info@instance-1.c.myproject.internal> SIZE=29
250 2.1.0 <info@instance-1.c.myproject.internal>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<example@email.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <example@email.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
```

My log file `/var/log/mail.log` show al lot of these kind of lines:

```
Aug 25 07:56:02 instance-1 sm-mta[19958]: u7OCN1Wu013988: to=<example@email.com>, delay=19:33:01, xdelay=00:10:36, mailer=esmtp, pri=5340422, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.72.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Aug 25 07:56:02 instance-1 sm-mta[19958]: u7OC9iDu013870: to=<example@email.com>, delay=19:46:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10560423, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Aug 25 07:56:02 instance-1 sm-mta[19958]: u7OBliSC013710: to=<example@email.com>, delay=20:08:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=10740386, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Aug 25 07:56:02 instance-1 sm-mta[19958]: u7O94ubM013110: to=<example@email.com>, delay=22:51:06, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=11460376, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Comment: Have you inspected sendmail's log files?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Check the output of my mail.log file in my question.

Comment: Looking at your logfile I would say that your host running sendmail is not able to connect to the internet. You can check this by running the following command from the terminal: nc alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25

Comment: @PeterSkarpetis I ran the command as you said, but I get nothing back and I am not able to type a command anymore. What does this mean?

Comment: It means you host cannot connect to the smtp server that handles mail for example@email.com. When I run the command I get the following output: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP x204si3583821ywa.112 - gsmtp . You will have to fix this issue before mail can work.

Comment: @PeterSkarpetis Okay, do you have any tips where do I have to start fixing this?

Comment: I thing I have pointed you in the right direction. Search google or stackoverflow for hints.

Comment: @PeterSkarpetis Okay thanks. I will. btw this is the message I got back after waiting a few minutes: `alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.72.27] 25 (smtp) : Connection timed out`

Comment: Exactly, the same message you get in the sendmail logfile.

Comment: You cannot send mail from Google Compute Engine, Google blocks all outgoing traffic on 25. You will have to use a third party like Sendgrid to send mail. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: @LennertKuijpers Yes, I had discovered this in the meantime. Is it right that it is also possible to use Google Apps as third party?

Comment: You can use Google Apps account to send emails from GCE instance by setting up a relay service. For more information you can visit [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/). If you have already resolved this issue you can post a self-answer so that the community can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send mail from Google Compute Engine, Google blocks all outgoing traffic on 25.

You will have to use a third party like [Sendgrid to send mail](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be possible to send email from the instance, everything is explained in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail).

By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports except port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All other ports are open, including ports 587, and 465.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to send email directly from your GCE VM.**

Please have a look at the documentation [Always blocked traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic):

> - Egress traffic to TCP destination port 25 (SMTP)

also at the [Using standard email ports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports):

> Due to the risk of abuse, **connections to destination TCP Port 25 are always blocked** when the destination is external to your VPC network. This includes using SMTP relay with Google Workspace.

Accordingly to the Wikipedia article [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol):

> Since SMTP's introduction in 1981, it was updated, modified and
> extended multiple times. The protocol version in common use today has
> extensible structure with various extensions for authentication,
> encryption, binary data transfer, internationalized email addresses.
> SMTP servers commonly use the Transmission Control Protocol on port
> number 25.

This was first decided back in 1982 with [RFC 821, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-44) and has been this way ever since. At the [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) you can see:

> **4.5.4.2.  Receiving Strategy**
>
> The SMTP server SHOULD attempt to keep a pending listen on the SMTP
> port (specified by IANA as port 25) at all times.

What does that mean? You cannot simply change the port, because there is no mechanism for other SMTP servers to know you are using a non-standard port, and you cannot either send to other servers using any other port.

**Is there a way to send emails from the GCE VM?**

Yes, let's get back to the documentation [Using standard email ports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports):

> Google Cloud does not place any restrictions on traffic sent to external destination IP addresses using destination TCP ports 587 or 465.

The ports 587 and 465 are available for SMTP Message Submission ([RFC6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409)). This means you can use an external mail relay (your own or 3rd party) for authenticated SMTP, and this server handles delivery to other mail systems on port 25. For example, you can use these 3rd party services: [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun), or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun). Also, you can relay your mails via [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) or just use [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com/).